# Best practice to build dynamic SQL queries

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am looking for some tips and tricks how to build dynamic queries. I am having an application which lets the user search 10 fields in the database table. Depending on which fields in the UI are filled with a value the query should search in an additional field in the DB.

Currently I am trying to build the query using StringBuilder and adding the where clause but I really don't like this and I am wondering if there is a better way to do this, for example with LINQ if possible.

Maybe someone can bring up ideas or better some example code. Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: How much data are you searching against, millions of records, hundreds, thousands and can you give a bit more information as to the frequency and number of concurrent searches you expect to be made?

Comment: the concurrent searches will be low, which means only 5 people will do e a few queries per hour in a day. In the table there are approx 800.000 records.

Comment: You may take a look at this codeproject.com article. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With LINQ it is pretty trivial:

```
IQueryable<User> users = db.Users;

if(name != null) users = users.Where(u => u.Name == name);
if(dept != null) users = users.Where(u => u.Dept == dept);
...

var page = users.OrderBy(u => u.Name).Take(100).ToList();
```

Each successive `Where` *composes* the query with more filters; exactly what you want.

With raw TSQL, `StringBuilder` isn't unreasonable; just make sure that you fully parameterize it. This might mean adding parameters in each term; for example:

```
...
if(name != null) {
    sql.Append(" and u.Name = @name");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", name);
}
if(dept != null) {
    sql.Append(" and u.Dept = @dept");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("dept", dept);
}
...
```

Comment: Just to add to this in case anyone is wondering about speed: Linq tends to work about as fast as stored procedures. But if you're needing a LARGE amount of speed for your search, you should consider a view with full text indexes.

Comment: wow. Yeah Linq looks really nice. It works nice. Should go much more into the Linq world with my code. Thanks again!

Comment: @Haedrian in most cases, especially since this is an equality search, standard non-clustered indexing will work just fine