# Insert command string building

Tags: c#

I could not find the error in the following insert command string. Let me know if you notice any. What is the best way to build this type of command string.It becomes very difficult to find error if whole string showing red ~.
I have picked every data value with pm. manually to avoid any chance or error.

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into ProjectMaster (ProjectCode, TransactionType, Description, Justification, RequesterName, RquesterID) values ('" +
    pm.ProjectCode + "','" + pm.TransactionType + "','" +
    pm.Description + "','" + pm.Justification + "','" +
    pm.RequesterName + "','" + pm.RequesterID  + "')", con);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Please, add error message which you have. Also google about SQL Injection

Comment: What indication do you have that there even *is* an error?  As for general advice on how to build a query, two things come to mind: 1) Don't use string concatenation, use parameterized queries; 2) Use carriage returns once in a while to make your code more human-readable.

Comment: When you get the parentheses in the right place, RquesterID might be your next issue. You'd also be a lot better off if thought about normalisation. If you do for instance have a Requester table, then an insert with a join, instead of sucking all the data down to the client would help a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the best way to build this type of command string.

You use parameterized SQL. Do *not* concatenate the values you want to use into the SQL like this. It opens you up to SQL injection attacks, conversion errors, and generally messy code.

You use code such as:

```
// Obviously fill in the "..." with the rest of the fields you need to use
string sql = "INSERT INTO ProjectMaster (ProjectCode, TransactionType, ...) "
           + "VALUES (@ProjectCode, @TransactionType, ...)";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        // Check the parameter types! We don't know what they're meant to be
        command.Parameters.Add("@ProjectCode", SqlType.NVarChar).Value = ...;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TransactionType", SqlType.NVarChar).Value = ...;
        ...
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Also, consider using an ORM instead of raw SQL.

Comment: some people say raw SQL performance better than ORM, is that true ?

Comment: @Selman22: Sometimes. Sometimes not. You need to check the performance and potentially tune it in both cases, and I suspect that for *most* applications, the difference after tuning is negligible. (It's not always the case, but I'd *start* with an ORM and then move to raw SQL just for the cases you need it for...)

Comment: And many ORMs will automatically map additional columns and properties and make it easier to keep code and DB in sync. Especially for such lengthy INSERT statements.

Comment: I have to use @ to assign it to a string and all has to put at one long line or "VALUES (@ProjectCode, @TransactionType, ...)" gives error.

Comment: @user2026794: It's not at all clear what you mean (in particular, "it gives error" gives us very little information), but you definitely *don't* need to put it all on one line. You can use string concatenation for the SQL itself (to put it on multiple lines, for example) - but *don't* include the values in the SQL.

Comment: The problem with using Parameter is you don't see the actual values used in the command line (in debug) to find where is a problem. In text visualization it just show list of field names and parameter names. I am getting "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" error but it is very hard to find error.

Comment: @user2026794: It really shouldn't be that hard - and you may find that if you look at the diagnostics on the server side, it gives you more information. You really *don't* want to stick the values straight in the SQL.

Comment: I agree 100% with you that parameters should be used. I was just trying to get any idea on how to debug Data type mismatch error, since I was not able to view the query with data.

Comment: @user2026794: Where exactly did you get the exception? Was it definitely when executing the query rather than whne binding the parameters?

Comment: I am getting error when executing the query. If I can find a way to identify which particular parameter is causing the error then that will be great help.

Comment: @user2026794: Well I'd get rid of half the parameters to start with... After going through each parameter carefully to try to spot the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I think your error might be here

```
pm.ResourceCount + "','" + pm.IssueFlag) + "')"
```

Should be

```
pm.ResourceCount + "','" + pm.IssueFlag + "')")
```

Basically, it looks like you are closing off your command string before adding the end brackets.  As others have suggested though, use parameterised SQL or other data access technologies instead of huge SQL strings.

Comment: I just pasted all that waffle into C# and it put the red squiggle there, so I thing you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever get into a situation where you have to write "generic code" that builds field lists at runtime. You still should not write your code the way you have (due to SQL injection among other things).

This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584812/best-practice-to-build-dynamic-sql-queries) has some useful suggestions, the Linq version is actually pretty simple and useful

Comment: Can you give any example of how to use Linq to insert records i database